# Why isn't this a compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I don't know what to call it I'll just provide a link. From what I can tell it is impossible, but why?

http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=structureId%3A1609384473364&source=calculate

Comment: Wow, trying to put cycloheptatrienyl inside cycloheptane - terribly strained bonds.

Comment: Apart from anything else the central ring won't be aromatic which is implied by the drawing. Try drawing with single/double bonds to see the problem.

Comment: @matt_black It could be as a tropylium type cation.

Comment: Chemicalize says it cannot calculate. I have no idea what your structure is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This structure is impossible as either the molecule is planar and then the C-C bonds on the outer ring are extremely long (and therefore weak), or you distort from the sp2 geometry (120 degree bond angles) of the central ring carbons so that the outer ring is beneath the inner one, which would also require a very high energy state. The only stable circumscribed ring structures you'll find are macromolecular.

Comment: So if this were made it would decompose or react instantly?

Comment: @tox123 Yeah, most likely.